# Scaffolding in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Whenever I start a new Java+Gradle project, I create the following directory structure manually:

```
project-name
  |
  |--- build.gradle
  |
  |--- .gitignore
  |
  |--- src
        |--- main
        |      |---java
        |
        |--- test
               |---java
```

Since this is a fairly standard structure, I imagine there must be a plugin/command/task for Gradle that would do this scaffolding for me. Is there such a plugin/command/task available? If not, can I write a task for that?

Comment: http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1289

Answer (score 16):

The following does the trick:

```
gradle init --type java-library
```

The task is provided by the [init plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html)

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this kind of scaffolding using an init script. Have a look at [my blog post about it](http://blog.proxerd.pl/article/my-gradle-init-script).

Answer (score 3):

There is a [templates plugin](https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-templates) available on github